# Is that possible to change streamName after livestream create?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I tried to use [livestream.update](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/update) reset streamName, but it return a error

```
{  "error": {   "errors": [    {
    "domain": "youtube.liveStream",
    "reason": "liveStreamModificationNotAllowed",
    "message": "Modification is not allowed in current state"    }   ],   "code": 403,   "message": "Modification is not allowed in current state"  } }
```

Is that possible to update or reset streamName after livestream created?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to update the streamName after the object is created. You can create a new liveStream object with the same settings and a new name.